# Error: Literal not terminated before end of script, en cadena totalmente delimitada

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando insertar unas etiquetas `script` pero me da problemas, el error que me muestra es el siguiente:

> literal not terminated before end of script

¿Qué puedo hacer?

```html
<script>
function script() {
  var content = "<script></script>"
}
</script>
```

Comment: agregarlas donde?

Comment: Te recomiendo que mires esta solucion, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30231151/syntaxerror-unterminated-string-literal-script-script-tag-not-working-wi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer mediante el método **[`createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)** de `document`. Luego le puedes agregar contenido y añadirlo al DOM.

Por ejemplo:

```js
function script() {
  //Creamos un elemento del tipo script
  var content = document.createElement('script');
  //Agregamos el contenido
  content.text = "alert('Hola me acabas de agregar al DOM :)')";
  //Lo ponemos en el head
  document.head.appendChild(content); 
  //Test del contenido por consola, borrar luego
  console.log(content);
}

script();
```

Siempre `createElement()` es la mejor opción para añadir elementos dinámicos en el DOM. Observa que este código hace lo que pretendes, sin ninguna complicación:

```js
function script() {
  var content = document.createElement('script');
  console.log(content);
}

script();
```

Answer (score 2):

Se puede solucionar usando una barra invertida (`\`) antes de la barra normal (`/`)... Ejemplo: `<\/script>`. De esta manera se evita que se cierre la etiqueta.

```
<script>
function script() {
  var content = "<script><\/script>"
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

El problema **exacto** es el *tag* `</script>` **dentro** de la cadena:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
var content = "</script>"
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

La consola del navegador muestra:

> SyntaxError: "" literal not terminated before end of script

No estoy seguro de que sea un error ... mas bien creo que es una *indeterminación* del estándar.

Si el navegador encuentra un *tag* `</script>` ... ¿ Sigue dentro de la cadena, o se nos olvidó indicar el final de la misma ?

Hay múltiples soluciones. Desde no usar esa secuencia exacta de caracteres (`'</script' + '>'` es admitido sin problema) hasta usar `createElement( )`.